# Longest answer ever?

Tags: discussion

Just wondering: what is the longest answer ever given in physics.stackexchange.com ?

Possible candidate: [What if the LHC doesn't see SUSY?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6438/what-if-the-lhc-doesnt-see-susy/6439#6439)

Comment: Shortest answer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38864/where-on-earth-can-you-find-plasma/38875#38875 according to [Data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/edit/124600) ( I copied David Zaslavasy's program below and changed DESC to ASC. )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually that comes in at #13. You're looking for [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/variation-of-delayed-choice-quantum-eraser/18612#18612).

Check out http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/64341/the-longest-answers

Comment: wow, thanks for sharing the cool toy. And yet that longest-answer-ever only got 0 vote...

Comment: And note that there is a system imposed limit on the length of any given post. I don't recall exactly what it is except that it is in the low 10's of thousands of character in the source.

Comment: @dmckee: I just tested it. It's 30000 characters.

Comment: Note that this answer is now out of date. As of today, the longest answer is [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74625/does-alternating-current-ac-require-a-complete-circuit/74999#74999)